# Quasar Framework Cypress Component test complains about Pinia

Tags: cypress, quasar-framework, pinia

I'm using the Quasar framework built on top of Vuejs and I'm trying to write a Cypress component test and I am getting the following error:

```
[]: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to 
install pinia?

const pinia = createPinia()

app.use(pinia)

This will fail in production.
```

I've tried adding the following to `commands.ts` but to no avail:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component) => {
  return mount(component, {
    global: {
      plugins: [createPinia()]
    }
  })
})
```

What is the proper way to include pinia in cypress so that any test of a component using pinia can execute properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it really simple. Just added the following to the `cypress/support/component.ts`

```
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia'

setActivePinia(
  createPinia()
)
```